# Why does my uv unwrap have a weird cut off?

Tags: texturing, uv, image, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

Why does my cylinder uv unwrap look like this? [image]

if you see the image is seamless but there is a random cut off where there are no other vertices so how is this happening?

Uv:

[image]

I don't think its because the uv is bigger than the picture because I always do that and this problem only started recently.

Comment: hello please pack the image and share your file